# Will my clothes still consider as impure (Napak) If I washed them alot?

Tags: taharah, self-purification

After masturbation, I found white spots on my pant (I don’t know whether it is Mani, Madhi or Wadhi). I washed that origin (where that spot was) gently with soap and leave it to dry. The next day I gave my clothes including the pant, to our maid to wash them. After the clothes get dried someone put them back in my wardrobe. When I opened my wardrobe I found still there was a spot on that pant.

**Question:** *If I washed my Napak (impure) cloths a lot and still there was a white-spot will it still consider Napak?*

**Question:** *If my clothes consider as Napak and someone puts them back in my wardrobe will all the Pak (pure) clothes that were in my wardrobe consider as Napak (impure)?.*

**Question:** *Can I gave my clothes ( those who had white-spot) to our Maid after washing that origin (where that white-spot was)?*

Comment: These are 3 different questions in one post questions 1 & 2 already has an answer on the site. And questions 3 honestly does not make sense to me?!

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your 2nd question is as follows. If the clothes which are napaak are wet and they come into contact then yes the clothes which come into contact with it will become napaak as this is transferring the impurity. If it is dry it will not be napaak however I suggest if you have any napaak clothing, to wash them and avoid keeping them with clean clothes. This could then lead to you having doubts which could possibly trigger waswas.

With regards to your 3rd question I presume you mean you will give her the clothes to wash in order to remove the najasah?